# TCP server in a docker swarm Deployment and docker swarm load balancing

Tags: python, docker, sockets, docker-swarm

I am trying to understand how the docker swarm does the load balancing and how it effects the design of the socket server (since the server has to accept the client connection to get the socket object that it uses to return the result of the service), to do this I created the following **echo server**:

```py
# server.py
class Server:
    def __init__(self, port=5050, header_size=64, encode_format='utf-8'):
        port = port
        host = "localhost"
        self.addr = (host, port)
        self.header_size = header_size
        self.encode_format = encode_format
        self.disconnect_message = 'DISCONNECT'

        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(self.addr)
        self.id = np.random.randint(1024)

    def do_stuff(self, conn, addr):
        msg_length = conn.recv(self.header_size).decode(self.encode_format)
        msg_length = int(msg_length)

        # THIS PART WAS REMOVED TO KEEP THINGS SIMPLE
        # message = conn.recv(msg_length) #.decode(self.encode_format)
        # while len(message) < msg_length:
        #     packet = conn.recv(msg_length-len(message)) #.decode(self.encode_format)
        #     message += packet

        print(f"[MSG] {msg_length} from {addr}")
        self.send(conn, f"{msg_length} response from {self.id}")
        return True

    def send(self, conn, msg):
        message = pickle.dumps(msg)
        msg_length = len(message)
        send_length = str(msg_length).encode(self.encode_format)
        send_length += b' ' * (self.header_size - len(send_length))

        # print("Sending response length")
        conn.send(send_length)
        # print("Sending response data")
        # conn.send(message)

    def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
        print("-------------------------------------")
        print(f"[CLIENT] new client {addr} connected.")
        connected = True
        while connected:
            connected = self.do_stuff(conn, addr)
        print(f"[CLIENT] {addr} has disconnected")
        conn.close()
        print(f"[Active CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() -2}")

    def start(self):
        self.server.listen()
        print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {self.addr[0]} port {self.addr[1]}")
        print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {self.addr[0]} port {self.addr[1]}")
        try:
            while True:
                print("Listening . . .")
                conn, addr = self.server.accept()
                thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
                thread.start()
                print(f"[Active CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() -1}")
                sleep(2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Interrupt signal received from Keyboard")
        self.server.close()
        print(f"[STOP] self.server {self.addr[0]} has stopped listening on port {self.addr[1]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.start()
```

I was able to run the server within a docker container using the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.9
COPY App /App
WORKDIR /App
RUN pip3 install -U pip
RUN pip3 install numpy
EXPOSE 5050
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "server.py" ]
```

**docker run command**:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 5050:5050 --name test IMAGE_NAME
```

**Client**

```
# Client
PORT = 5050
HOST = "SERVER_IP" # or the IP of the server if is running on a different machine
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
HEADER = 64
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = 'DISCONNECT'

def send(sock, msg):
    message = pickle.dumps(msg)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))

    sock.send(send_length)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(ADDR)
for i in range(200):
    msg = f"Message number {i}"
    send(sock, msg)
    response = receive(sock)
    print(response)
sock.close()
```

but when deployed in a in a docker swarm service the client hangs on `sock.connect()`
(I have 2 worker nodes and 1 manager node in the swarm )

**service create command:**

```
sudo docker service create --name echo_server -p 5050:5050 --replicas 2 PRIVATE_REGISTRY_IP:PORT/IMAGE_NAME:TAG
```

All swarm server examples I found use the nginx image which I was able to deploy on a worker node then access it using the IP of the manager node (Which is what I am trying to achieve for a TCP socket server).

1. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there something different in the design of the TCP socket server that I should do?
3. How is the client connecting to the server with the implementation of the swarm load balancer?
4. Is it always being sent to the same server that it was first connected to?
5. Is every request sent to a different server?
6. Do all the servers have 1 client which is the load balancer (in that case there is no need to open a thread for every thread), and the load balancer has the info of the clients?

**Solution**

I was able to deploy the server in a stack

**stack.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  echo_server:
    image: REGISTRY_IP/IMAGE_NAME
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

and then run

```
sudo docker stack deploy -c /path/to/stack.yaml STACK_NAME
```

and then the client was able to connect to the service through the host IP of one of the worker/manager node PCs

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work, even without Swarm: the server listening on `localhost` won't be accessible from outside its own container, and the client connecting to `localhost` is trying to connect back to the itself and not the server container.  If you fix these problems so it works in plain Docker, does it also work in Swarm?

Comment: My localhost client is on the same manager machine, so when i connect to localhost, the load ballancer should be able to redirect me to the container (at least that is what happened when i ran the nginx example, but with the python socket server it did not),  I also tried adding the IP of the manager node and it gave me a connection refused Error. When I added the IP of the worker node that has the container running it hanged on sock.accept() as I explained in the question. To avoid any further confusion I am going to edit the question so the client connects to the server IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker swarm has, for this purpose, two load balancers:

The ingress load balancer is invoked when you publish a port from a service.  That port is published from all swarm nodes, so any node can be used to connect to the service. And docker will round-robin connections to any available (healthy) service replicas.

Because this traffic arrives over a bridge interface, you cannot listen on "localhost" as that will prevent the container actually listening for bridged connections.

Note that while each swarm node would accept connections from localhost:port to connect to the ingress network, containers cannot use "localhost" to connect to it as that refers to the localhost interface inside the container, not the host. The correct way to connect to the current local host from inside a container would be the address: "docker.host.internal:8080" (this needs to be enabled on each service that needs to use it).

the other load balancer is the mesh networking load balancer. When deploying a service in a stack, docker modifies the resolve.conf in each container to point to a docker resolver that will resolve the service names for each network the container is attached to.
Docker swarm also creates a virtal-ip for the service which is a layer 3 load balancer, and associates it with the dns name for the service on each network.

So, if you deployed a service called "echotest" as part of a stack called "test", and 2 replicas were created then docker would assign the following:

A vip with the ip 10.0.1.5 with the names "echotest" and "test_echotest".

Two tasks, with the IPs 10.0.1.6 and 10.0.1.7 respectively.

Any other service attached to the "test_default" network (10.0.1.0/24) would be able to use the names "echotest" and "test_echotest" to connect to the vip, which in turn would actually connect to one of the containers.

A service that did its own load balancing could use the special names "tasks.echotest" and "tasks.test_echotest" to get a dns rr response: just the task ips with their order randomised. [10.0.1.6,10.0.1.7]

This set of commands shows the results on my swarm.

```bash
$ docker network create --attachable --driver overlay test
$ docker service create --network test --replicas 2 --name test-nginx nginx:latest
$ docker run --rm -it --network test nicolaka/netshoot
$ dig test-nginx +short
10.0.38.2
$ dig tasks.test-nginx +short
10.0.38.3
10.0.38.6
$ exit
$ docker service rm test-nginx
$ docker network rm test
```

Comment: "docker.host.internal:8080 (this needs to be enabled on each service that needs to use it)" how do I enable it, I tried adding it to the swarm service with `--host .docker.internal:host-gateway` and it kept failing, I tried to add `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to my container run command and got a `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: Im not sure which version added it specifically, but it should be available on docker 20.10.x so start by checking that. `--host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` should work on docker service create.
Just verified that `docker service create --host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --tty --name test_netshoot nicolaka/netshoot` adds a host.docker.internal entry to the containers /etc/hosts.

Comment: I just checked my image, it also addded <host.docker.internal> to /etc/hosts however when I run the server.py after changing `host = "localhost"` to `host = "host.docker.internal"` I get `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to bind to that address, to listen on it, rather than use it to connect. In the server app, your host needs to be "0.0.0.0", or a lookup on the hostname. Its the client that needs to connect using host.docker.internal.

Comment: but the client will not be in the swarm, it will run on the local/external network and should connect to the service through the manager node IP:SERVICE_PORT and the load balancer should route it to the server that will serve the client/request.

Comment: Also will the load balancer route the client or the request? So if the client sends a connection request will all requests sent by that client be serviced by that server or will each request be distributed to the next available server?

Comment: If the client is external to docker, then you need to publish the port and ingress networking is used. The client would connect to "swarm-node-ip:5050" and each connection would be round-robin connected to a different server.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, the publish is done using the -p as stated above, the node IP is not the same as the HOST_PC_IP, I can find the NODE_IP when inspecting the node from the manager under Status->Addr

Comment: `-p 5050:5050` publishes port 5050 in the container as 5050 on the host. "NODE_IP" is whatever ip can be used to access the node from the PC you are running the client on. If you are running the client on the same PC as you are running docker and the server, you can use localhost. If its different, its the IP that you normally use to reach the server.

Comment: I have the server running on all 3 nodes (manager+2 workers) connected to the manager, I am on the manager node, let's assume that one of my nodes have an IP of `192.168.1.200` the client should connect to `192.168.1.200:5050` but I get a `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`. And that i s was what I was originally doing. I also tried localhost since my manager node is also a worker node and has a container from the swarm running.

Comment: Then your linux distribution probably has a firewall that you need to configure to allow overlay networking.

Comment: There i no firewall and everything is running on the local network, the weird thing is when I deployed as a stack, everything worked fine, what the hell?